# How to create GeoJSON object using Java driver in Mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am a newbie in MongoDB. Can anyone tell me how I can create a simple GeoJSON object ? I will be working with GeoSpatial queries hence I need some basic help with creating a GeoJSON object using Java Mongo driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the SpringData Mongo driver. It has methods in the `Criteria` object to create the kind of query you want:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html

The official Java driver for MongoDB is really not very good. The equivalent JavaScript commands are distributed unevenly across the Java API, and sometimes you're required to do what @Sambhav-Sharma says: just pass MongoDB operators as strings.

Comment: The Mongo doc refers to "legacy coordinate pairs" a lot. Is it not correct to use them with Lat and Long replacing x and y?

Comment: The "legacy coordinate pairs" refers to the format of point coordinates before Mongo 2.4. It was a planar system. Mongo now supports spherical and 2d. Legacy is version 1 of the "2dsphere."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create separate GeoJSON objects using Java Driver. You will have to use query builders to produce GeoJSON queries.

Use Basicdb objects and append Geo data to the objects.